# How to add link to a string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add Link in a string of a component but I'm having issues that it displayed as a Object Object.

I add productPage link as object or as a component to my Tooltip component.

How can I achieve it in this situation?

Here is my code base:

Tooltip.js:

```
const useStylesBootstrap = makeStyles({
  arrow: {
    color: "#e06a56"
  },
  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: "#e06a56",
    fontSize: 11,
    width: '180px'
  }
});

function BootstrapTooltip(props) {
  const classes = useStylesBootstrap();

  return <Tooltip arrow classes={classes} {...props} />;
}

export default function CustomizedTooltips(props) {
  return (
    <BootstrapTooltip title={props.content}>{props.button}</BootstrapTooltip>
  );
}
```

App.js:

```
const renderHideOptionalClauseTrigger = () => {

  const productPage = () => {
    return (
      <Link to="/product">
        Product page
      </Link>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <text>My Optional Loan Clause</text>
      <Tooltip
        button={
          <span>
            <i className="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
          </span>
        }
        content={
          `Will be added verbatim as last clause to the loan agreement. See ${productPage} for other clauses.`
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Updated! If I put my link like this

```
const productPage = <Link className="orange-link" to="/product">Product page</Link>
```

it will be come Object Object..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely need to use a JSX Element—otherwise it will convert your Link to a string (and display [object Object]):

```
content={
      <>Will be added verbatim as last clause to the loan agreement. See {productPage} for other clauses.</>
    }
```